# Jquery auto complete query that match a string word by word

Tags: mysql

I have implemented jquery auto complete in PHP and MySql where i have string like this:

> nokia lumia 1020

if user type

> nokia 1020

then the query should match above string word by word. Here is my query.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE model LIKE :term');
$stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
```

any suggestion please ?

Comment: are you using php and mysql ?

Comment: I have mentioned in my question i think

Comment: any issue you are getting ?